# Sorting a woocommerce subcategory for breadcrumb

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have Wordpress installation with woocommerce. The problem i have is while using multiple sub categories for a product. We get different breadcrumbs for each product. I'm trying to use woocommerce breadcrumbs to use only one of the sub category as a breadcrumb while avoiding other sub categories.

Current Structure:

```
Parent Category

   -Sub Category 1
   -Sub Category 2
   -Sub Category 3
   -Sub Category 4
```

I want only "Parent category -> Sub Category 1" to appear in the breadcrumbs avoiding other sub categories.

The term_ids of the categories are in ascending order. For example

```
Parent Category (term_id = 11)

   -Sub Category 1 (term_id = 12)
   -Sub Category 2 (term_id = 13)
   -Sub Category 3 (term_id = 14)
   -Sub Category 4 (term_id = 15)
```

I've checked the class-wc-breadcrumb.php file and wc-term-functions to find a solution. But was unable to make it sort by term_ids.

I'm using the Newspaper theme.

Comment: default woo commerce give such facility can you give more info about your question..

Comment: what would you like to know? I only want the  wc_get_product_terms function to sort with term ids

Comment: your breadcrumb comes according to your url means if you are in "Sub Category 1" then it show  "Parent category -> Sub Category 1" breadcrumb.